# Problema exportando Unity para APK

Tags: unity3d, apk

Quando tento "exportar" para APK recebo o seguinte erro:

> Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:/sdk-tools\tools\aapt.exe',
>   CommandLine='package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M
>   "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I
>   "C:/sdk-tools\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_',
>   CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process)
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
>   ()

Answer (score 0):

Isso daí não parece ser uma mensagem de erro. Parece ser uma mensagem que informa qual é a linha de comando que o Unity está executando para construir o seu APK.

Comment: Concordo. Mas isso não é uma resposta e sim um comentário, não? :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Pensei em postar como comentário originalmente, mas daí fiquei a pensar o que viria a ser uma resposta para esta pergunta. Cheguei a conclusão (talvez equivocada) de que o meu comentário era a resposta.

Comment: É que como vc mesmo coloca, a pergunta não está clara. Falta a mensagem de erro (que deve existir).